# How to capture and display d3.json http status code 500

Tags: d3.js

I am getting a 500 from the d3.json api call.  But I don't see a way in the documentation to capture the error message and display it.  Anyone have any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first argument to the callback function to `d3.json()` is an error object that captures and describes the error. If the request was successful, the error will be `null`.

```
d3.json(url, function(error, data) {
  // do something with error
});
```

See [the documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Requests#wiki-d3_json).